# disable bootstrap popover on a specific day click in fullcalendar js

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, popover

I am using fullcalendar js. On dayClick function I have binded a bootstrap popover. It is working fine. But I want to disable the popover on specific dates on click.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
left: 'prev',
center: 'title',
right: 'next'
},
defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
editable: true,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
businessHours: true,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,

dayClick: function(event,element,start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {  



$(this).popover({
html: true,
placement: 'right',
title: function() {
return $("#popover-head").html();
},
content: function() {
return $("#popover-content").html();
},
html: true,
container: '#calendar'
});
$(this).popover('toggle');


var eventData;
eventData = {
title: title,
start: start,
end: end
};
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
//$('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

if(event.id='unavailable'){
$(this).popover('disable');
}
},




events: [



{
id: 150,
title: 'Conference',
start: '2015-02-09',
status : 'Production',
editurl :'http://yahoo.com',
createurl : 'http://google.com',
},

{
id: 151,
title: 'Lunch',
start: '2015-02-09',

status : 'Approved',
editurl :'http://yahoo.com',
createurl : 'http://google.com',
},

{
id   : 152,
title: 'Dinner',
start: '2015-02-11',
status : 'Exported',
editurl :'http://yahoo.com',
createurl : 'http://google.com',
},
{
id   : 153,
title: 'Birthday Party',
start: '2015-02-13',
status : 'Idea',
editurl :'http://yahoo.com',
createurl : 'http://google.com',
},
{
id: 154,
title: 'New Event',
start: '2015-02-20',
status : 'Recurring',
editurl :'http://yahoo.com',
createurl : 'http://google.com',
},
{ 
id: 155,
title: 'Repeating Event',
start: '2015-02-22',
status : 'Idea',
editurl :'http://yahoo.com',
createurl : 'http://google.com',


},
                                { 
id: 156,
title: 'New Event',
start: '2015-02-22',
status : 'Idea',
editurl :'http://yahoo.com',
createurl : 'http://google.com',


},
// areas where "Meeting" must be dropped
{
id: 'availableForMeeting',
start: '2015-02-12',
end: '2015-02-17',
rendering: 'background',
color:"#7ce51f",

},

// red areas where no events can be dropped
{
start: '2015-02-24',
end: '2015-02-28',

rendering: 'background',
color: '#ff9f89'
},
{
id: 'unavailable',
start: '2015-02-06',

end: '2015-02-08',
overlap: false,
rendering: 'background',
color: '#ff9f89'
}


]
});



$("#calendar").find('.fc-prev-button').children('span').removeClass('fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow').addClass('fa fa-arrow-left'); 
$("#calendar").find('.fc-next-button ').children('span').removeClass('fc-icon fc-icon-right-single-arrow').addClass('fa fa-arrow-right');
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you please update your formatting as this code is nearly unreadable

Comment: the code have been updated. Can I have a help now?

Answer (score 0):

Add in `date` to your call back function and do logic to figure out if the day is a day that should or shouldnt pop up the popover.

```
 dayClick: function(date, event, view) {
        var placementDate = $(this).data('date');

        var yesNo = "2015-05-13";            //Can do Moment Date logic here if you want to make it nicer

            if(yesNo == placementDate){
                 //Do nothing
            }
            else{
                $(this).popover({
                   html: true,
                   placement: 'right',
                   title: function() {
                   return $("#popover-head").html();
                   },
                   content: function() {
                   return $("#popover-content").html();
                   },
                   html: true,
                   container: '#calendar'
                   });
                   $(this).popover('toggle');
            }

 }
```